# How do I return a web page's table cell value without ID, using column and row names (not index)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

Most questions about Python and Selenium scraping a web page's table data involve a table with an ID or Class, and some index technique using a count of rows and columns. The Xpath technique is usually not explained either.

Say I have a table without an element ID or class, let's use [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) for example.

I want to return the value 'Johnson', without counting row or column numbers.

Here's my attempt (edited)...

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import contextlib
url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    columnref = 3
    rowref = 4
    xpathstr = '//tr[position()=' + str(rowref) + ']//td[position()=' + str(columnref) + ']'
    data = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathstr).text
print data
```

I have gotten some good help here already, but am still using an index. I need to generate 'columnref' and 'rowref' by looking up their values. 'Last Name', and '3' respectively.

Comment: this is not the correct form of `xpath`. provide `html` part of code for your table

Comment: @Andersson -  Cheers I updated the question:)

Comment: @drets That wasn't very nice. Well I have unmarked it, in hope of this person doing it. In the mean time I'm working the remainder out for myself instead of complaining about someone only doing 75% of my work for me.

Comment: Question has been up voted ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this css selector to reach the cell you want `tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(3)`, and you can generate css selector for any cell with the same way. See below:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(3)")
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10fdd4510>
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(3)").text
u'Johnson'
```

Alternatively, you can use `position()` tag to locate cell position. See below:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[position()=4]//td[position()= 3]").text
u'Johnson'
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[position()=5]//td[position()= 3]").text
u'Smith'
```

If you want to get the text by **column name** and **row number** you can write a function that returns the value by finding the index of the column then getting the text as below:

```
def get_text_column_row(table_css, header, row):
    table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(table_css)
    table_headers = table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th')
    table_rows = table.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)")

    index_of_column = None
    index_of_row = None

    for i in range(len(table_headers)):
        if table_headers[i].text == header:
            index_of_column = i + 1

    for i in range(len(table_rows)):
        if table_rows[i].text == row:
            index_of_row = i + 1

    xpath = '//tr[position() = %d]//td[position() = %d]' %(index_of_row, index_of_column)

    return driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
```

and use it like below:

```
>>> get_text_column_row('#main > table:nth-child(6)', 'Points', '3')
u'80'
>>> get_text_column_row('#main > table:nth-child(6)', 'Last Name', '3')
u'Doe'
>>> get_text_column_row('#main > table:nth-child(6)', 'Last Name', '4')
u'Johnson'
```

Comment: I thought you right click in inspector and 'Copy unique selector' of the table body. How did you arrive at yours for future reference?

Comment: Also, this is using an index. How can I return the text using the column name and a row identifier?

Comment: 5 years ago I did it that way :) . It is just a simple css selector.

Comment: I don't follow your comment. Is it possible to look up the value with column name 'Last Name' and ID ('Column Number' - not count) '3'?

Comment: @square_eyes question is now more clear. Let me check it.

Comment: @square_eyes updated the answer for your updated info see it

Comment: This is helpful, but how can I return using column and row names, not index? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98500/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-mesut-gunes).

Comment: @drets in the example row is number and if it was string it could be written same as column name.

Comment: @MesutGüneş What would the xpath be for row headers?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: run table_cell_value.py
Johnson
```

**table_cell_value.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

COLUMN_NAME = 'Last Name'
ROW_NAME = '3'

JS_SCRIPT = """
var row = column = -1;
var table = arguments[0];

for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[0].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
    if (table.rows[0].cells[c].innerHTML === arguments[1]) {
        column = c
    }
}

for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    if (table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML === arguments[2]) {
        row = r
    }
}

if (row < 0 || column < 0) {
    return
}

return table.rows[row].cells[column].innerHTML
"""


browser.get('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp')
table = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('table')
print browser.execute_script(JS_SCRIPT, table, COLUMN_NAME, ROW_NAME)
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement

Comment: Thanks, but why did we have to us js?

Comment: @drets I added the code for missing part. Check my answer